# Ingame goback not working

Tags: android, android-activity, back

Ok my game starts with 2 buttons:
One is the new game with this code:

```
    case R.id.newgame:
        openNewGameDialog();
        break;

    private void openNewGameDialog() {
    new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
    .setTitle("new game")
    .setItems(R.array.difficulty,
     new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialoginterface,
              int i) {
           startGame(i);
        }
     })
    .show();
}




   private void startGame(int i) {
    Log.d(TAG, "clicked on " + i);
    Intent intent = new Intent(SudokuActivity.this, Game.class);
    startActivity(intent);
    intent.putExtra(Game.KEY_DIFFICULTY, i);

}
```

Ok,now the game has started.Let's assume I play it 2 minutes,and then decide to go on the menu,so I press the BACK button on my phone.The menu appears,but now I wanna go back to my game and continue from where I left off.

I tried to put finish(); on the continue button,but when I press it,it just gets me to the main android screen.

Comment: ofcourse is for android! is a very basic sudoku game

Comment: I have also tried this code on the continue button:                      Intent intent = new Intent();
                setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);
                finish();                                                           It doesn't work...

Comment: I was just checking, since you never mentioned it and there was no Android tag. Have you implemented the onPause, and onResume methods? These are where you store user data while you wait for them to return.

Comment: Also, as far as I know, finish will close the application...so calling it in a method that is supposed to load your previous progresses is probably a bad idea...

Comment: i didn't...I'm a beginner and I don't really know how everything works. Could you help me with that please?

Comment: Read the section on activity lifecycle:http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Game Activity you must override onPause method, and call you save logic. You may use SQLite, or file, to store activity state. And in onCreate or onResume of Game load this data(if exist) and resume game.
It`s correct work even if main activity crashed, or user push Home btn.